# How to use a cookie in routing configuration in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, cookies, routes

I have a `City` parameter stored in a cookie. I would like to include its value as a pattern prefix in my routing configuration like so:

```
# MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

MyBundle_hotel:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing/hotel.yml"
    prefix:   /%cityNameFromCookie%/hotel
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give us a use case on how you would want this to work because I don't see the difficulty. Routes are made of parameters that you can specify through the `generateUrl` function, the `url` twig function or the `path` twig function.

In Twig you can do this

```
{{ path('MyBundle_hotel', {cityNameFromCookie: app.request.cookies.get('cityNameFromCookie')}) }}
```

In a controller action

```
$cookieValue = $this->get('request')->cookies->get('cityNameFromCookie');
$url = $this->generateUrl('MyBundle_hotel', array('cityNameFromCookie' => $cookieValue));
```

Or from any places that have access to the container

```
$cookieValue = $this->container->get('request')->cookies->get('cityNameFromCookie');
$url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('MyBundle_hotel', array('cityNameFromCookie' => $cookieValue));
```

In the last example, you will probably want to change how the container is being accessed.

If you are concerned about how complicated it looks like, you can abstract this logic and put it inside a service or extend the `router` service.

You can find documentation about [services and the service container in the Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

You can also list the services via the command `php app/console container:debug` and will find the `router` service and its namespace and from this you can try to figure out how to extend the `router` service (a very good way to learn how services work).

Otherwise, here is simple way to create a service.

In your services.yml (either in your Bundle or in app/config/config.yml)

```
services:
    city:
        class: MyBundle\Service\CityService
        arguments: [@router, @request]
```

In your `CityService` class

```
namespace MyBundle\Service

class CityService
{

    protected $router;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct($router, $request) 
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function generateUrl($routeName, $routeParams, $absoluteUrl)
    {
        $cookieValue = $this->request->cookies->get('cityNameFromCookie');

        $routeParams = array_merge($routeParams, array('cityNameFromCookie' => $cookieValue));

        return $this->router->generateUrl($routeName, $routeParams, $absoluteUrl);
    }
}
```

Anywhere you have access to the container, you will be able to do the following

```
$this->container->get('city')->generateUrl('yourroute', $params);
```

If you still think that it isn't a great solution; you will have to extend the router service (or find a better way to extend the router component to make it behave the way you are expecting it to).

I personally use the method above so I can pass an entity to a `path` method in Twig. You can find an example in my [MainService class](https://github.com/Cornichon/ForumBundle/blob/master/Service/MainService.php) and [PathExtension Twig class](https://github.com/Cornichon/ForumBundle/blob/master/Extension/Path.php) defined in the [services.yml](https://github.com/Cornichon/ForumBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml).

In Twig, I can do `forum_path('routename', ForumEntity)` and in a container aware environment I can do `$this->container->get('cornichon.forum')->forumPath('routename', ForumEntity)`.

You should have enough information to make an informed decision

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I find tedious and inefficient to retrieve the cookie in every controller, and add its value to every generated path in every template. Can I inject the cookie value from a service into the router?

Comment: Yes, you have to inject the router service into your custom

Comment: Your previous comment seems to be cut short. Would you mind updating your answer with more details on how to inject the cookie value into the router with a service?

Comment: I've updated my answer above and given you as much information as I could.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is greater than anyone could have hopped. Live long and prosper.