# What's the best way to implement a Symfony2 age gateway/verification

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create an age gateway/verification bundle for Symfony2. I'm new to the framework and not sure of the right way to implement it.

So far I have it set-up as a voter but it appears you then have to call isGranted() with a role on every action you want the gateway to show up. The problem is that, at that point, I don't think the user has a role.

This leads me to believe that I should be doing things differently, e.g., firewall or a listener maybe.

Can someone please advise on the best method along with some background info/links to help get me started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at a an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620088/how-to-use-a-cookie-in-routing-configuration-in-symfony2), a simple way to do this would be to create a twig template which checks for the presence of a cookie using:

```
{% if app.request.cookies.has('someCookie') %}
```

If that's not present, then you can inject the required Javascript to display a popup, insert a META REFRESH to force a redirect, or some other action.